# Does OpenCL/Cuda memory leak if not Unloaded? Problem with allocating/loading GPU memory in Module

Tags: cudalink, opencllink

The GPU memory manager documentation is not too clear, does GPU memory leak if not explicitly unloaded or if the symbol that holds the reference to the GPU memory gets collected, the GPU memory gets freed too?

In my experience, MemoryInUse doesn't grow if I keep loading GPU memory (but losing the symbols, e.g., the memory is in temporary variables), but MathKernel.exe memory usage does!

My problem in this matter is that I have to allocate GPU memory in Module[] temporary variables, so I don't have (well know) any way of unloading it manually afterwards... Is there a way to add a "destructor" to Mathematica symbols, so I can manually call Unload when the symbol is reclaimed?

This MathKernel behaviour is observed on Mathematica 8.0